# Why is my margin-top not working?

Tags: html, css

I have a list of images that I'm trying to move but it isn't working.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="wrapper">
           <h1>Portfolio</h1>
           <img src="assets/img/PHOTOGRAOHY.png" alt="Photography" width="214" height="183">
           <img id="industrialDesignIMG" src="assets/img/ID.png" alt="Industrial Design" width="232" height="183">
           <img src="assets/img/GraphicDesign.png" alt="Graphic Design" width="233" height="196">
           <img src="assets/img/animation.png" alt="Animation" width="198" height="142">
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
​
```

**CSS:**

```css
#industrialDesignIMG {
    border:1px #fff solid;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 80px;
}
#wrapper {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

I want `#industrialDesignIMG` to have a `margin-top` of `80px`, but either nothing moves or all the `img` elements move. What can I do to get my `margin-top` working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Images are inline elements. To fix this float each image to the left, this will make it a block element:

http://jsbin.com/ekojux/1/

```
img { float: left }
```

Answer (score 6):

It actually *is* being applied. It's just that since the images are all inline elements, they're inline with each other, so is appears they're all being shifted down 80 pixels because the images align at the bottom.

See [this JSFiddle without the top margin](http://jsfiddle.net/roddy/y752p/) and [this JSFiddle with the top margin](http://jsfiddle.net/roddy/D5CAD/).

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```css
padding-top: 80px;
```

or:

```css
position: relative;
bottom: -80px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Float all of the images left.

```
img {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default positioning of any element is static. Hence the ordering/positioning of any element will vary depends on the position of sibling elements.
To be simple, just add CSS `float: left` to the image tags and assign margin for your specific image. Example:

```css
#wrapper img { float: left; }
```

Now add margin to your `#industrialImg`. This move your header to corner. Just wrap all the `img` with a new `div`. That should work.